# iterate through files in python script and execute bash command

Tags: python, samtools

I am trying to write a python script that loops through SAM files in a directory and uses `samtools view` to convert those SAM files to BAM files. Here's what I have, but am struggling with how to input the SAM file (i) into the bash command in the last line.

```
import os
import glob
for i in glob.iglob('/file/path/to/files/*.sam'):
      os.system("samtools view -S -b %i > %i.bam" %i)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be best using classic string concatenation techniques to achieve this. You can basically just add the result into the `os.system` call.

You could rewrite it to something like:

```
import os
import glob

for file in glob.iglob('/file/path/to/files/*.sam');
    command = "samtools view -S -b " + str(file) + " > " + str(file) + ".bam"
    os.system(command)
```

You could even use the format option instead:

```
command = "samtools view -S -b {} > {}.bam".format(file, file)
```

The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) does a good job about explaining how you can do these sorts of operations.

Answer (score 3):

With up-to-date Python version you can use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) where f stands for formatting.

```py
os.system(f"samtools view -S -b {i} > {i}.bam")
```